# Как установить nodejs из архива в ubuntu 14.хх?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

Качаю архив [node-v4.2.2-linux-x64.tar.gz](https://nodejs.org/en/), распаковываю его в `/home/ivan/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64`, а что нужно сделать дальше?

UPD:
В readme написано -

### Build

#### Unix / Macintosh

Prerequisites:

- `gcc` and `g++` 4.8 or newer, or
- `clang` and `clang++` 3.4 or newer
- Python 2.6 or 2.7
- GNU Make 3.81 or newer
- libexecinfo (FreeBSD and OpenBSD only)

`text
$ ./configure
$ make
$ [sudo] make install`

но где это нужно выполнить? В корне распакованного архива пишет

```
ivan@pc:~/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/bin$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: Нет такого файла или каталога
ivan@pc:~/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/bin$
```

что это может быть? Получается что все что касается ноды имеет вот такие ошибки..

Еще UPD:
из корня тоже не работает

```
ivan@pc:~/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: Нет такого файла или каталога
ivan@pc:~/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64$
```

Comment: А разве в ubintu нет стандартного пакета node.js ? как то не верится. думаю стоит ставить через менеджер пакетов. ну либо как со всеми исходниками configure, make, make install

Comment: @Mike Вы не человек чтоль? В вопросе, который я задал десять минут назад, Вы написали те же команды. Я попросил Вас рассказать немножечко подробнее, на что Вы ответили, чтобы я создал новый вопрос. Я его создал, а Вы опять по новой. Ну ладно, попрошу ещё раз - можно немножечко подробнее? Я никогда не ставил так и по этому мне эти команды ничего не говорят.

Comment: Хм. вы о каком вопросе, я не видел никаких подобных вопросов, и за всю неделю на SO не давал ни разу таких рекомендаций

Comment: @Mike точно, сорри. У меня уже разум помутился из-за ноды. Такая вроде мелочь, а уже пол дня отобрала.

Comment: @Mike я кстати дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, на любой системе должно работать:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Не знаю, зачем вы хотите вручную сбилдить...ну да ладно:

```
apt-get install make g++ libssl-dev git
#распаковали в node-v4.2.2-linux-x64
cd node-v4.2.2-linux-x64
./configure
# билдить надо в корневой папке ноды
make -jX
#если всё ок, то
make install
```

Comment: через манагер ставится первая версия...

Comment: есть разница между распаковать вручную и программно? Просто если нет, то не работает. Обновлю вопрос..

Comment: @shatal вы же билдите в папке bin...

Comment: Вы видимо посмотрели раньше чем я обновил. Ещё раз посмотрите.

Comment: Ради прикола взял архив, который с таким именем на сайте ноды. Это уже собранная версия. там бинарник. configure есть только в папке модулей, но надо ли их собирать. учитывая что никаких мейкфайлов там в корне в помине нет, и инструкций так же, то единственный путь раскладывать руками все по системе. просто содержимое папок типа bin, lib, includes аккурантно раскладывать по системе в аналогичные папки в /usr

Comment: Я всегда через `sudo apt-get install nodejs`. Мне хватало )

Comment: А Вы не знаете, можно это как-то за один раз скопировать? Или правда нужно до последней вложенности руками?

Comment: @shatal вы о чём?

Comment: Я о том что если бы все это происходило в винде, то можно было бы просто содержимое ноды кинуть в папку /usr/ и они бы сами встали куда нужно. Можно так сделать в ubuntu? Когда Вы говорили о ручном размещении, то подразумевали что содержимое этого архива годное и его только перекинуть в /usr осталось? И меня не устраивает. По не ручному можно установить только v0.10.25 а сейчас уже 4.5.x которые и быстрее и es6 поддерживает

Comment: @shatal да там вроде ничего копировать не надо. После `make install` оно само всё установит.

Comment: Вот теперь Вы о чем?) Вы говорите - там нет "чего-то" по этому нужно руками по папкам раскладывать. Я переспрашиваю Вас о конкретном подходе, а Вы говорите что все само разложится после ``make install ``. Так руками или само?

Comment: @shatal вы, вероятно, меня с Mike перепутали. Это он советовал )

Comment: да :) Вечно лезет не туда )))))

Comment: @Mike Вы опять меня попутали :) Тогда повторю вопрос для Вас - если бы все это происходило в винде, то можно было бы просто содержимое ноды кинуть в папку /usr/ и они бы сами встали куда нужно. Можно тоже самое как-то в ubuntu сделать? Типа sudo "все из распакованного архива" перекинуть в "/usr" ?

Comment: Копирует команда cp. Но я все таки не рекомендую тупо распаковывать архив в /usr. Вы должны точно знать, какие файлы вы туда положили. Потому как после этого действия автоматическая установка пакетов в вашей системе над частями node.js, а может и еще над чем то будет невозможна. В крайнем случае, станьте рутом `su -` и ввести пароль рута, запустите `mc` он вам позволит наглядно увидеть что и куда вы копируете. Только не удалите случайно что нибудь. Если mc у вас нет - то `sudo apt-get install mc`

Comment: @Mike нет, я тогда вообще не буду. Пусть это просто останется камнем в сторону повернутых на ubuntu. Как минимум ubuntu не предназначена для разработки на ноде. только для верстания, да и то с чувством что ты убогий и используешь нуливые версии. А спустя ещё полгода и того не сможешь использовать плагины пятой версии. Стремная ubuntu.